# Como construir un numero unico a base de varios numeros

Tags: algoritmos

Buenas a todos, para explicar mejor lo que quiero saber es dando a saber para que lo usare.

Con una clase llamada `Personaje` quiero saber como está vestido, bastaría con crear varias variables donde se almacena un número que identifique el sprite que va a usar, ejemplo:

```
Personaje:
    cabeza = 5
    cuerpo = 3
    brazos = 88
    pantalon = 23
    zapatos = 18
```

Pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma eficiente de hacerlo con una sola variable, asi:

```
Personaje:
    sprite = 183
```

Ahora lo que deseo saber es cómo puedo hacer para construir un número basado en los 5 valores antes mencionados y luego descomponerlo y obtener nuevamente los 5 valores. ¿Ya existe una fórmula o algoritmo para esto?

Esto es mas por saber que por necesidad, se que usando arrays se solucionaría todo facilmente.

**Edito para los que estan respondiendo**: Sus soluciones estan buenas y muy correctas, pero no es exactamente lo que quiero, mi solucion debe ser mas por conocimientos matematicos/algoritmos/ecuaciones que por soluciones de programación, las soluciones que me estan dando son basicamentes crear arreglos o tipos de datos/clases. Un ejemplo de lo que quiero seria algo similar a esto:

```
ancho = 20
alto = 15
tamaño = ancho * alto
mapa = Array.new(tamaño)
mapa[x + y * ancho] = tile_id
```

Algo parecido a eso me gustaria lograr, en la unica solucion que yo puedo llegar con mis conocimientos seria creando un buffer, tal que asi:

```
buffer = "000000000000000" #=> Cada 3 digitos es un valor
```

ejemplo de uso:

```
cabeza = 5
cuerpo = 49
brazos = 0
pantalon = 186
zapatos = 650
buffer += cabeza #=> "005 000 000 000 000"
buffer += cuerpo #=> "005 049 000 000 000"
buffer += brazos #=> "005 049 000 000 000"
buffer += pantalon #=> "005 049 000 186 000"
buffer += zapatos #=> "005 049 000 186 650"

valor final de buffer = "005049000186650"
```

Es una solucion, pero aun asi hay que establecer el tamaño del buffer y no es una formula matematica que me gustaria conocer, gracias a todos por sus comentarios y respuestas! :)

Comment: vas a utilizar algún lenguaje de programación en concreto?

Comment: Utilizo mucho Ruby, pero en concreto cualquier lenguaje me sirve, pero si lo preguntas porque en algun lenguaje existe una libreria que ya hace esto, me gustaria saberlo y asi tengo como buscar sobre el tema, la verdad me ha ido muy mal buscando informacion de como hacer esto, no se como expresar con exactitud lo que quiero :(

Comment: A raiz de tu edicion y solo por curiosidad, ¿hay alguna razón de fuerza mayor por la que "debas" hacerlo asi y no con objetos/structs/diccionarios/arrays?

Comment: @Kenny Ninguna, en lo absoluto amigo, solo por puro saber/conocer, de hecho la idea me vino ya que haciendo un cliente/servidor en puro Ruby de un Juego, queria simplemente tratar de enviar paquetes de informacion lo mas livianos posibles, y para no usar: @socket.send("<085><#{cabeza}><#{cuerpo}><#{brazos}><#{pantalon}><#{zapatos}></085>") es mejor usar algo como: @socket.send("<085><#{sprite_id}></085>"), gracias por responder amigo!

Comment: Entiendo. En ese caso ya he dado mi voto a la respuesta de @DavidIsla que es la mejor para tus necesidades. Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para mi, quien mejor resuelve esto es C/C++, a través de las `union`

En una `union` diferentes estructuras y tipos comparten el mismo espacio de memoria, por lo que puedes manejar la información por separado o todo junta. Por ejemplo:

```
union Personaje
{
    struct 
    {
        char Cara;
        char Pelo;
        char Cuerpo;
        char Piernas;
    } grupos;
    int32_t codigo;
};

int main()
{
    Personaje prueba;

    prueba.grupos.Cara = 21;
    prueba.grupos.Pelo = 88;
    prueba.grupos.Cuerpo = 15;
    prueba.grupos.Piernas = 77;

    std::cout << prueba.codigo << std::endl; // Esto devuelve 1292851221

    prueba.codigo = 1292851222; // Si cambio el valor....

    std::cout << (int)prueba.grupos.Cara << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)prueba.grupos.Pelo << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)prueba.grupos.Cuerpo << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)prueba.grupos.Piernas << std::endl;

}
```

La salida del ejemplo anterior sería:

```
1292851221 
22 
88 
15 
77
```

En este ejemplo, una estructura (grupos) de 4 `bytes` (cada `char` es un `byte`) y un entero (código) igualmente 4 `bytes` comparten la misma memoria:

```
 -Byte- -Byte- -Byte- -Byte- 
-----------------------------
| Cara | Pelo | Cuer | Pier | <- Si accedes por la struct grupos
-----------------------------
|        c o d i g o        | <- Si accedes por la variable codigo
-----------------------------    
<--------- 32 bits --------->
```

Este método tiene como ventaja que no tienes que andar haciendo transformaciones o calculando, cualquier cambio que realice en una de las variables afectan inmediatamente a todas las demás.

Comment: Wow! esta solución es muy buena, similar a la que puse al editar la pregunta, muchas gracias por responder, aun me quedo con la duda de como se pudiera hacer con una ecuación pero esta respuesta es bastante acertada, lo único malo es que es una solucion que requiere C/C++, muchas gracias amigo y suerte! :).

Answer (score 0):

Es posible, lo que tendrías que hacer es primero tener definidos todos tus catálogos con sus respectivos valores:

- Cabeza
- Cuerpo
- Brazos
- Pantalón
- Zapatos

Ya que los tengas definidos, debes de crear otro catalogo Sprite's que va a contener todas las posibles combinaciones que pueden existir de tus elementos y puedes crear tu numero identificador en base a los identificadores de cada elemento aunque no te recomiendo generar el identificador de Sprite de esta manera ya que se te podría repetir, mejor generarlo de otra forma y asignarlo a cada combinación así cuando generes ese Sprite puedes saber que elementos contiene.

Te recomiendo estudiar sobre probabilidad, simulación y generación de pseudoaleatorios, te podría orientar mejor.

Comment: Es buena solucion, pero es algo pesada no crees? basicamente es crear un array conteniendo todas las posibles combinaciones, quedo en lo mismo, se que suena algo caprichoso pero quiero hacerlo de la manera que lo explique, gracias por contestar amigo!! XD

Answer (score 0):

Ya que ciertamente estarás usando programación orientada a objetos, se me ocurre que sería bueno seguir el paradigma de programación y usar un objeto para solucionar tu problema. Ciertamente usando arrays es una posible solución.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una clase que se llame `sprite`, instanciar la clase y "guardar" en el objeto los números o variables que necesitas. En un pseudolenguaje (inventado para esta ocasión jajaja), podrías pensar en algo como esto:

```
clase Sprite
    definir constructor(a,b,c,d,e)
        cabeza = a
        cuerpo = b
        brazos = c
        pantalon = d
        zapatos = e
```

Entonces en tu clase `Personaje` puedes tener una propiedad que sea de tipo `Sprite`, algo asi:

```
clase Personaje
    definir constructor(Sprite a)
        sprite = a
```

Entonces, un ejemplo de código funcional en este "pseudolenguaje" podría ser el siguiente:

```
s = new Sprite(5,3,88,23,18)
p = new Personaje(s)
```

Y entonces ya puedes hacer refencia y saber los valores de las partes del cuerpo directamente del objeto, **con referencia a una sola variable que es** `p`. Siguiendo este paradigma, puedes escalar el código facilmente por si llegaras a necesitar más partes del cuerpo o algo asi, e igualmente solo necesitarias de la variable `p`.

Esta es la idea. Puedes trasladar esta idea muy fácilmente a cualquier lenguaje de programación orientado a objetos. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Olvide decirlo pero edite la pregunta para aclara mejor el método que quisiera para la solución, muchas gracias por responder amigo lo aprecio!

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí, cuando crees un nuevo personaje puedes pasarle un diccionario de los tipos:

```
class Personaje:
    def __init__(self, tipos):
        self.tipos = tipos

    def get_sprite_types(self):
        # Retorna una lista o array de los tipos de vestimenta usados
        return list(self.tipos.keys())

    def get_sprite_values(self):
        # Retorna una lista o array de los valores de cada vestimenta
        return [self.tipos[x] for x in self.tipos]

    def get_sprite(self):
        # Calcula la suma de los valores de cada tipo de vestimenta
        return sum(self.get_sprite_values())
```

Ahora, para crear el personaje:

```
>>> tipos = {'pantalon': 23, 'zapatos': 18}
>>> personaje = Personaje(tipos)
>>> personaje.tipos
{'zapatos': 18, 'pantalon': 23}
>>> personaje.get_sprite()
41
>>> personaje.get_sprite_values()
[18, 23]
>>> personaje.get_sprite_types()
['zapatos', 'pantalon']
>>> tipos_usados = personaje.get_sprite_types()
>>> print('Vestimenta usada para el personaje: {}'.format(', '.join(tipos)))
Vestimenta usada para el personaje: zapatos, pantalon
```

Está en lenguaje Python pero creo que es bastante entendible. La idea es que después de crear el personaje tengas acceso a cada tipo de vestimenta con la que fue creado y también al valor total de `sprite`.

Comment: Olvide decirlo pero edite la pregunta para aclara mejor el método que quisiera para la solución, muchas gracias por responder amigo lo aprecio!

Answer (score 0):

Se me acaba de ocurrir, no lo veo muy eficiente pero supongo que 'encaja' en lo que buscas, ¿no has pensado en concatenar?

```
Personaje:
    cabeza = 5
    cuerpo = 3
    brazos = 88
    pantalon = 23
    zapatos = 18
```

Antes de concatenar, reservas los primeros dos dígitos (o los que quieras) para indicar de cuantos ceros es el separados.

Por ejemplo: `0350003000880002300018`

Aquí indicas con los dos primeros dígitos (`03` = 3) que hay tres ceros como separador, es decir, cada vez que el programa se encuentre con tres ceros seguidos, se pasa al siguiente campo.

Desglosado:

`03` `5` -000- `3` -000- `88` -000- `23` - 000 - `18`

Con un separador de 6 sería: `0650000003000000880000002300000018`

`06` `5` -000000- `3` -000000- `88` -000000- `23` - 000000 - `18`

El separador lo ajustas según los ceros que tenga tu programa, en este caso como ningun valor tiene un cero, el separador más apropiado sería 1: `01503088023018`

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder amigo, tu solución es muy parecida a la que propuse en la pregunta, el separador no es necesarios si le das un tamaño en digitos a cada variable, mira mi pregunta de nuevo, justo al final, esta clase de sistema al estilo buffer es bueno, pero quisiera una solucion al estilo 'semilla' como la respuesta de @David Isla. De nuevo muchas gracias por responder!

Answer (score 0):

Estoy respondiendo mi propia pregunta es porque encontre una solucion basandome en la respuesta de @David Isla.

Esta solucion la hice en Ruby y es una forma de hacerlo sin uso de Uniones de C/C++, basicamente lo que hago es transformar a binarios las 5 variables, y luego lo sumo, despues la suma la transformo a su equivalente en numero y listo, despues solo queda transformar ese numero de vuelta a binario y agarrar los bytes que le corresponde a cada numero, les daré un ejemplo de lo que hice en Ruby:

```
# Esta funcion sirve para obtener el valor binario de un numero en forma de string.
# number => Numero a obtener el valor binario.
def get_binary(number)
    binary = number.to_s(2) # Retorna el string en binario, tambien se puede usar: binary = "%b" % number
    byte_size = 1 * 8

    # Si el tamaño de un binario es menor que el tamaño dado se agregan ceros(0) al inicio del binario, ejemplo:
    # byte_size = 8
    # binary = 18.to_s(2) #=> "10010" solo 5 digitos, faltan 3 para que sea del tamaño de byte_size
    # binary = "000" + "10010" = "00010010" = 18
    #
    # Para ahorrarnos todo esto podemos simplemente usar: "%tamaño_en_bytesb" % number
    # Ejemplo: "%08b" % number
    if binary.size < byte_size
        binary = ("0" * (byte_size - binary.size)) + binary
    end
    return binary[0...byte_size]
end

class Player
    attr_accessor :head, :body, :arms, :pants, :boots
    # Retorna la suma binaria de todos los numeros requeridos
    def get_seed
        return (get_binary(self.head) + get_binary(self.body) + get_binary(self.arms) + get_binary(self.pants) + get_binary(self.boots)).to_i(2)
    end
    # Transforma la semilla en binario y va retirando la cantidad de bytes desde el final de el codigo binario.
    # Ejemplo:
    # 1. [                                                       ] = "1001000011010010000010101100001100011"
    # 2. ["01100011"                                             ] = "10010000110100100000101011000"
    # 3. ["01100011", "01011000"                                 ] = "100100001101001000001"
    # 4. ["01100011", "01011000", "01000001"                     ] = "1001000011010"
    # 5. ["01100011", "01011000", "01000001", "00011010"         ] = "10010"
    # 6. ["01100011", "01011000", "01000001", "00011010", "10010"]
    # 7. [        98,         88,         65,         26,      18]
    def set_seed(seed)
        binary = seed.to_s(2) # El binario es la representacion binaria de la semilla en string.
        byte_size = 1 * 8
        array = []
        while true
            # Salir del bucle si la semilla esta vacia.
            if binary.size == 0
                break
            end
            # Si el tamaño de los binario es menor que el que se desea sacar significa que es el ultimo elemento
            # asi que se termina el bucle.
            if binary.size < byte_size
                value = binary.to_i(2)
                array.push(value)
                break
            end
            # Sacar un valor de el binario.
            value = (binary[binary.size - byte_size...binary.size]).to_i(2)
            binary = binary[0...binary.size - byte_size]
            array.push(value)
        end
        array.reverse!
        self.head = array[0]
        self.body = array[1]
        self.arms = array[2]
        self.pants = array[3]
        self.boots = array[4]
    end
end

personaje = Player.new
personaje.head = 18
personaje.body = 26
personaje.arms = 65
personaje.pants = 88
personaje.boots = 98
p personaje.get_seed #=> 77749901410
print("\n")

personaje2 = Player.new
personaje2.set_seed(personaje.get_seed) #=> 77749901410
p personaje2.head  #=> 18
p personaje2.body  #=> 26
p personaje2.arms  #=> 65
p personaje2.pants #=> 88
p personaje2.boots #=> 98
print("\n")

personaje2.set_seed(personaje.get_seed + 1) #=> 77749901411
p personaje2.head  #=> 18
p personaje2.body  #=> 26
p personaje2.arms  #=> 65
p personaje2.pants #=> 88
p personaje2.boots #=> 99 <<<< Cambio
```

Para los que programan en Ruby les digo que lo programe así para que sea mas universal en lo que a lenguajes de programación se refiere. Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas fueron de mucha ayuda, suerte! :)

Answer (score 0):

Como cada numero se puede descomponer de manera única en producto de primos. Asigno a cada parte un rango de números primos que no se pueden repetir y deben ser continuos para poder identificar a que rango corresponde cada uno.

Este es mi código en c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsolePersonaje
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88139/como-construir-un-numero-unico-a-base-de-varios-numeros
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] cabezas = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
            int[] cuerpos = new int[] { 13, 17, 19 };
            int[] brazos = new int[] { 23, 29, 31, 37 };
            /*Cada numero se descompone como productos de primos de manera unica.*/
            int unico = cabezas[1] * cuerpos[2]* brazos[0];

            Personaje person = new Personaje(unico);

            int cabeza = person.Cabeza;
            int cuerpo = person.Cuerpo;
            int brazo = person.Brazo;

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Cabeza: {0} Cuerpo: {1} Brazo: {2}", cabeza, cuerpo, brazo));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class Personaje
        {
            private int _numero;
            private List<int> _factores;

            public Personaje(int p)
            {
                this._numero = p;
                this._factores = FactoresPrimos(p);
            }

            /*Funcion que descompone en factores primos*/
            public List<int> FactoresPrimos(int p)
            {
                List<int> result = new List<int>();
                if (p == 1)
                    result.Add(p);
                else
                {
                    while (p > 1)
                    {
                        int div = 2;

                        while (p % div != 0)
                            div++;

                        p = p / div;
                        result.Add(div);
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }

            public int Cabeza
            {
                get
                {
                    foreach (var fac in this._factores)
                    {
                        //rango de cabezas: 2, 3, 5, 7
                        if (fac >= 2 && fac <= 7)
                        {
                            return fac;
                        }
                    }

                    return 0;
                }
            }

            public int Cuerpo
            {
                get
                {
                    foreach (var fac in this._factores)
                    {
                        //rango de cuerpos: 13, 17, 19
                        if (fac >= 13 && fac <= 19)
                        {
                            return fac;
                        }
                    }

                    return 0;
                }
            }

            public int Brazo
            {
                get
                {
                    foreach (var fac in this._factores)
                    {
                        //rango de Brazos
                        //23, 29, 31, 37
                        if (fac >= 23 && fac <= 37)
                        {
                            return fac;
                        }
                    }

                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muy buena idea amigo! me hubiera gustado mucho una respuesta así hace unos días cuando buscaba como hacer esto, había visto un vídeo sobre criptografía usando números primos en Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8K311s7EiM), el método se llama RSA, pero fue después de este post así que ya estaba satisfecho y no quise tratar de hacerlo en Ruby, viendo tu código me motive y lo hice :). No soy experto en lo que a C se refiere, pero creo que seria bueno hacer a "cabezas", "cuerpos" y "brazos" static, así se hacen constantes. Gracias por responder y suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Respondo de nuevo mi pregunta para mostrar otra posible solución mostrada por @Urres.Alejandro, aquí el código en Ruby:

```
# Metodo escrito por: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/30418/urres-alejandro
def factores_primos(n)
    result = []
    if n == 1
        result.push(n)
    else
        while n > 1
            div = 2
            while(n % div != 0)
                div += 1
            end
            n = n / div
            result.push(div)
        end
    end
    return result
end

# Detecta una cantidad de numeros primos.
def numeros_primos(cantidad)
    result = []
    n = 1
    while(result.size < cantidad)
        a = 0
        for div in 1..n
            if n % div == 0
                a += 1
            end
        end
        result.push(n) if a == 2
        n += 1
    end
    return result
end

class Player
    primos = numeros_primos(1000)
    HEAD = primos[0...200] #=> 0 hasta 199
    BODY = primos[200...400] #=> 200 hasta 399
    ARMS = primos[400...600] #=> 400 hasta 599
    PANTS = primos[600...800] #=> 600 hasta 799
    BOOTS = primos[800...1000] #=> 800 hasta 999
    def initialize(head = 0, body = 0, arms = 0, pants = 0, boots = 0)
        @head = head
        @body = body
        @arms = arms
        @pants = pants
        @boots = boots
    end
    def get_seed
        return (HEAD[@head] * BODY[@body] * ARMS[@arms] * PANTS[@pants] * BOOTS[@boots])
    end
    def set_seed(seed)
        ids = factores_primos(seed)

        # El metodo Array#index retorna la hubicacion en el array del valor que pases, ejemplo:
        # array = ["Juan", "Pedro", "Gabriel"]
        # array.index("Juan") #=> 0
        # array.index("Pedro") #=> 1
        # array.index("Gabriel") #=> 2
        @head = HEAD.index(ids[0])
        @body = BODY.index(ids[1])
        @arms = ARMS.index(ids[2])
        @pants = PANTS.index(ids[3])
        @boots = BOOTS.index(ids[4])
    end
    # Metodo llamado cuando se quiere mostrar una clase en Ruby.
    def inspect
        string = "Head: #{@head}\n"
        string += "Body: #{@body}\n"
        string += "Arms: #{@arms}\n"
        string += "Pants: #{@pants}\n"
        string += "Boots: #{@boots}"
    end
end

player1 = Player.new(4, 180, 100, 70, 68)
p "Semilla del 1 jugador: #{player1.get_seed}" #=> 3484027755527363

player2 = Player.new
player2.set_seed(player1.get_seed) #=> Head: 4
                                   #=> Body: 180
                                   #=> Body: 180
                                   #=> Arms: 100
                                   #=> Pants: 70
                                   #=> Boots: 68
p "Semilla del 2 jugador: #{player2.get_seed}" #=> 3484027755527363

p player2
```